# execute query with cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want to execute a query to get my data
how can I write this query with cakephp

```
select materiel_id , SUM(quantite)  from paiements  

GROUP BY
  materiel_id

ORDER BY sum(quantite)
```

Thinks,

PS : I use cakephp 2.3.6

Comment: What did you try so far? Note that you should be using http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html . Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you ca us this code

```
$mat=$this->Materiel->Paiement->query("
        select *,materiel_id , SUM(paiements.quantite) as t from paiements ,materiels
        where paiements.materiel_id=materiels.id
        GROUP BY
          materiel_id
        ORDER BY sum(paiements.quantite) desc
            ");
```

Ajust this code for your model

Comment: The query is possible without using Model->query. I think most people advise to use Cake's built-in query helpers such as find('all') and find('first'), etc and only user Model->query as a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

Well assuming you have the model relationship Paiement belongsTo Materiel and you are in the PaiementsController

```
$this->Paiement->find('all',
    array(
        'group' => array('Paiement.materiel_id'),
        'fields' => array('Paiement.materiel_id),
        'contain' => array(
            'Materiel' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'SUM(Paiement.quantite) AS sum'
                ), 
                'order' => array(
                        'sum' => 'desc'
                ),
            ), // Materiel
        ) // contain
    ) // end array
); // end find
```